# Having issues with Multiple AJAX refresh and TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tinymce

So I'm running into this predicament.

```
<SCRIPT src="../js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
   tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "simple"
   });
</SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT src="../js/admin.js"></script>
```

The above is called on my PHP page.

I'm then calling

```
var request = $.ajax(
{
   url:"getEvents.php",
   type:"POST",
   data:{'method':'showevents'},
   dataType:"html"
   }).done(function(msg){
        $('#eventlistbody').html(msg);
   }); 

   setTimeout(
        function(){
            $(".mceSimple").each(function(){
              tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl",false, this.id);
           })
   },2000);
```

this loads a bunch of textareas.....
the tinyMCE will load on all the text areas the first time it returns..when I click on the reload which runs the above again and returns the text areas they no longer have the tinyMCE attached to them. 
I'm not sure why it works the first time and not subsequent times.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should shut down tinymce correctly before you reload in order to be able to reinitialize a tinymce editor after the reload has been made. This is necessary because tinymce does not like to be dragged around the dom. And initialized editor instances may have one one unique id (using reload will force tinymce to try to initliaze a second editor with the same id - which will fail).

**Tinymce3:**
To shut down an edtor instance use:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true, editor_id);
```

To reinitialize use

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',true, editor_id);
```

**Tinymce4:**
To shut down an edtor instance use:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor',true,editor_id);
```

To reinitialize use

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor',true,editor_id);
```

Comment: thanks for the information I discovered that at about 3AM yesterday and didn't have time to post a response. Great information.

Comment: @dpDesignz: this solution works for tinymce3 only, to make it applyable to tinymce4 you will need to replace mceRemoveControl with mceRemoveEditor and mceAddControl with mceAddEditor. see my updated answer

Comment: @Thariama awesome thanks! :D Unfortunately it didn't do what I was hoping it would :( Please see my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730342/reinitialize-tinymce-4-in-ajax

Answer (score 2):

For me tinyMCE.remove(editor_id) worked.

Answer (score 1):

**Tinymce4: To shut down an edtor instance use:**

```
tinymce.remove();
```

or indicate one unique id

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor',true,editor_id);
```

**To reinitialize use**

```
tinymce.init(conftinymce);
```

or indicate one unique id

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor',true,editor_id);
```