# TinyMCE editor not loading properly

Tags: javascript, php, html, tinymce, textarea

I am trying to load tinyMCE editor into div , on ajax call.

When 'add' button clicks ,first time it loads text area with toolbars.

But from second time onwards , it appends textarea to the previously loaded textarea , and tool bar at the proper.

**First click :**

[image]

**Second click :**

[image]

here is the code :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var id=0;
         $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#add").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({url: "add.php", type: "POST", data: ({id: id}), success: function(result) {
                        $("#div1").append(result);
                    }});
                  id++;
            });

            $("#remove").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var lastNode = $("#div1").children().last();
                lastNode.prev().remove();
                lastNode.remove();
            });
        });

         </script>
      <div id="div1">
      </div>
```

**add.php**

```
<?php
$id=$_POST['id'];
?>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea#area<?php echo $id; ?>",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
 </script>

 <textarea style="width: 300px; height: 100px;" id="area<?php echo $id;?>" name="value[]"></textarea>
```

why it is not appending properly.whats wrong ?

Comment: [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14978745/1188035)