# Reinitialize TinyMCE 4 in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, tinymce-4

I'm using TinyMCE in an ajax enabled [Foundation Reveal](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html) box. Now the TinyMCE kicks in the first time it loads, but if I close the box and open it again it doesn't trigger :(

I have other scripts like [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) and [masked input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) triggered in the exact same fore query that work, but TinyMCE will not reinitialize when I reload it a second time

This is my code currently that I'm trying as recommended at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971384/having-issues-with-multiple-ajax-refresh-and-tinymce/14978745):

```
$(document).on('opened.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
    $("#expenseUser, #expenseVendorID, #expenseCategoryID, #expenseAccidentID").chosen({disable_search_threshold: 5, width: '365px'});
    $("#expOdo").mask("999999",{placeholder:"0"});
    $('.datePicker').each(function() {
        $(this).datetimepicker({
            addSliderAccess: true,
            sliderAccessArgs: {touchonly: false},
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            altField: "#"+$(this).attr('id')+"Alt",
            altFieldTimeOnly: false,
            altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            altTimeFormat : "HH:mm:ss",
            dateFormat: "D, d MM yy",
            timeFormat: "hh:mmtt"
        });
    });
    tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor',true,"textarea#expenseComments");
    tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor',true,"textarea#expenseComments");
    tinyMCE.init({selector: "textarea#expenseComments",menubar : false,toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright"});
});
```

**UPDATED**

I've tried changing to the following with luck, but I think this is the right path to go down?

```
$(document).on('opened.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
    $("#expenseUser, #expenseVendorID, #expenseCategoryID, #expenseAccidentID").chosen({disable_search_threshold: 5, width: '365px'});
    $("#expOdo").mask("999999",{placeholder:"0"});
    $('.datePicker').each(function() {
        $(this).datetimepicker({
            addSliderAccess: true,
            sliderAccessArgs: {touchonly: false},
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            altField: "#"+$(this).attr('id')+"Alt",
            altFieldTimeOnly: false,
            altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            altTimeFormat : "HH:mm:ss",
            dateFormat: "D, d MM yy",
            timeFormat: "hh:mmtt"
        });
    });     
    tinyMCE.init({selector: "textarea#expenseComments",menubar : false,toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright"});
}); 
$(document).on('close.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
    tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor',true,"textarea#expenseComments");
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem here is that closing the box without shutting down the inner tinymce instance properly will result in not showing the editor the second time (because there is still a tinymce editor object in the variable window.tinymce.editors).

**Solution**: onclose (in fact before destroying or removing) of the box shut down the editor.

Comment: Thanks for this! Can you please see what I've tried in my update? It's still not triggering for some reason :(

Comment: Looks like you are not using the proper tinymce id. The editor id is the same id your textarea posseses. Try this: tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor',true,"expenseComments");

Comment: [@Thariama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/346063/thariama) Can you please make any workaround for this. And I'm using it with Ajax load within the same page itself, not with modal. That's why I'm facing this issue and still can't get how to resolve this.

Comment: @ManoMahe I haven't worked with Tinymce for some time now, so i am not up to date with the newer versions. Can you create a jaFiddle (jsfiddle.net) for it, so that  iam able to see what happens?

Comment: [@Thariama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/346063/thariama), Thanks for the effort. I found the mistake which I have made and rectified now by myself. I loaded the scripts with every Ajax call response page, which made the issue on my side. Now I have moved those scripts into the parent file, then everything is working well now

Answer (score 7):

## 2020 Update

To remove existing tinymce editor and add new needs clearance of tinymce.EditorManager.editors array.
This solution works in both cases :

1. If you have only one editor and you want to remove and add it again.
2. If you have multiple editors and you want to remove some special editor and add it again.

```
console.log(tinymce.EditorManager.editors);
```

This will give you a view of the array and exact index of you desired editor which you want to remove. For example one sample output of above console can be:

```
Array[2]
0:B
1:B
length:2
textarea-1:B
textarea-2:B
_proto_Array[0]
```

This is the output of the console when i have two tinymce editors on textareas : #textarea-1 and #textarea-2
Lets suppose I want to delete #textarea-2 and re-add it then it can be done as follows:

```
tinymce.EditorManager.editors.splice(1, 1);//removing second element in array.
delete tinymce.EditorManager.editors['textarea-2'];//deleting respective textarea id from array
```

Then you can add it again simply using init:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector:'#ts-textarea-2'
});
```

If you have only one textarea associated with tinymce editor lets say : #textarea-1 and you want to remove and re-initialize it then you can just empty
tinymce.EditorManager.editors by :

```
tinymce.EditorManager.editors = [];
```

And then you can add using init command as explained above. Worked for me without any error.

*I hope it helps*

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a timing issue. I am looking into doing an event listener type of thing instead of a timer, but when I wrap my init function, it works properly. I found the hint from this post here: http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=32661

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, 'editorId');
setTimeout(function() {
    tinyMCE.init(myconfig);
}, 3000);
```

Comment: I didn't need the setTimeout, but the mceRemoveEditor command worked great! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Need to clear the old instances of tinymce. Following code worked for me

tinymce.EditorManager.editors = []; //we need to remove the old instances.

//Set "About" section to a TinyMCE editor.
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  skin_url: '/packages/teamon_tinymce/skins/lightgray',
  menubar: false,
  toolbar: 'insert | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist',
});
tinymce.get('pageContent').setContent(page.content);

Answer (score 0):

Hoping this will be a more complete guide to solving this.

```js
console.log("before remove")
//capture the editorId from this (id: )
console.log(tinymce.EditorManager.editors);
//remove instance 
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, "editorId");
//add to the DOM the html to whom you will apply tinymce
$("#emailEditor").append(html);
console.log("before add")
console.log(tinymce.EditorManager.editors);
//add instance
tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, "editorId");
//init tinymce
initTinyMce();

//be sure to add the init_instance_callback part
function initTinyMce() {
    console.log("init tinymce")
    tinymce.init({
        //script_url: '~/Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tiny_mce.js',
        selector: "textarea#editorId",
        // General options
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "modern",
        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: true,
        init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
            var currentEditor = editor.editorContainer;
            $(currentEditor).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you improve your answer explaining which was the problem so future users can find your answer more useful?

Answer (score 0):

this solved my issue:

```js
// Remove all editors bound to divs

tinymce.remove('div');

// Remove all editors bound to textareas
tinymce.remove('textarea');

// Remove all editors
tinymce.remove();

// Remove specific instance by id
tinymce.remove('#id');
```

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/?_ga=2.143898737.597721600.1600176559-1290517464.1591019990#remove